# ons-switch with ny-model and ng-change doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I have ons-switches which generated by ng-repeat and bind each element to specific model, but when I changed its value from HTML it doesn't update model value.

Here is the example code

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in Items">
    <ons-switch ng-model="item.selected"></ons-switch>
</ons-list-item>
```

in angular file

```
$scope.items=[
    {
        id:'id1',
        text:'text1',
        selected:false
    },
    {
        id:'id2',
        text:'text2',
        selected:false
    },
    {
        id:'id3',
        text:'text3',
        selected:false
    }
];
```

if I changed model value manually, ons-switch state changed.

P.s. I'm using onsen UI 1.2.1 for cordova application

Comment: Could you provide som more code? What does `$scope.Items` contain? In this example it works fine: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/myqzNQ

Comment: Please look at edited code. I don't know why it doesn't working in my code. Thanks for your example code anyway. Could you provide the onsen ui js file?
I might use the old one.

Comment: I notice you use ons.bootstrap at the begining. is it necessary?

Comment: woops.. i wrote i wrong logic in my program...sorry :) onsen ui works well.

Comment: No problem. Great that you were able to solve it. :)